# Dismiss a progressdialog and trigger another one

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, progressdialog, timertask

my goal is to dismiss the initial progressdialog if there's no internet connection (let's say after 10 seconds) and then trigger another alertdialog whice prompts the user to check his internet connection and try again.

here is my RemoteDataTask class :

```
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        /*
        Create the progressdialog
         */
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        //title :
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("SmartShop. Shopping made easy !");
        //message :
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Chargement...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        //show the progressdialog...Only if gpslocation is available !! :)
        if (gps.canGetlocation()){
            mProgressDialog.show();
            }
        //mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        long delayInMillis = 3000;
        list_of_articles = new ArrayList<Articles>();
        try {
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        },delayInMillis );
            // Locate the class table named "Article" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Article");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            //query.orderByAscending("ranknum");
            query.whereWithinKilometers("Localisation_Vendeur",device_location,rayon);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject article : ob) {
                // Locate images in article_image column
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) article.get("Image_Article");

                Articles map = new Articles();
                map.setArticle_name((String) article.get("Nom_Article"));
                map.setArticle_vendor((String) article.get("Nom_Vendeur"));
                //map.setArticle_vendor((String) article.get("reduction"));
                map.setArticle_image(image.getUrl());
                list_of_articles.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                list_of_articles);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }



}
```

my progressdialog does not dismiss with this code. what's wrong with it ? and where should I call the second alertdialog "check internet connection and try again" ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should perform UI modifications only from the UI thread. `Timer` runs its tasks in its own thread, not in the UI thread. You can do something like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}});
```

And start a new dialog in the same way.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I dont understand that part "You should perform UI modifications only from the UI thread". can you point me to a tutorial/documentation please ?
BTW I moved the timer to the onPreExecute function, and now the prgressdialog does dismiss.

Comment: @RidouaneHicham http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html